# Looking for a specific horror gaming podcast

Tags: product-identification, horror, modern, podcast

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I'm trying to find a specific horror gaming podcast I listened to a few episodes of way, way back.

Things I know about it:

- It had one, male, speaker.
- It had a horror theme, possibly with an emphasis on modern day adventuring.
- My best guess for the date I was listening to it was summer, 2009. It *could* have been summer 2007 or 2008 though. It could not have been after 2009 (the last time I spent the summer in the location I know I listened to it.) Of course, I could have been listening to older episodes, but this is the best I have.
- One of the early episodes had a review of four horror adventures. I think they were modern day adventures, but I'm not sure on that.

Things I might be confusing with another podcast:

- I think the author tried to use the ransom model to raise funds. Specifically, if this is the same podcast, he made 4 additional episodes and set a goal for them. If the goal was reached then they'd be released and everyone would get them free. My memory of this is less clear then the rest, however. The number four is clear, but it could have been a different podcast or not additional episodes that were being ransomed. If this wasn't the same podcast it was one that was on the web at the same time, as I listened to them the same summer.

(I have a very clear memory of listening to the podcast I'm looking for at a specific park while walking the dog. I've got another memory of listening to a similar podcast at another nearby location and remember hearing about the ransomeware model as a solution to piracy, and my problems with it. These could have been the same podcast, or just two I listened to that summer together. Either way, the ransomeware model was only popular for a short period, and was never that popular so I'm hoping it was the same podcast and someone remembers it.)

Comment: "shot in the dark." Horror podcast. I get it.

Comment: @nitsua60 ....actually that was unintentional.

Comment: I'm not actually sure if this is the type of question we can answer. I'd love to know

Comment: @PremierBromanov It is specific enough that I think it has a chance. There are a lot of people around who listened to gaming podcasts in that era, and it had some specific features. It is definitely answerable, the question is if anyone knows what the answer is. I can't have been the only person to listen to it.

Comment: @PremierBromanov the wiki for [tag:product-identification] says "I remember something about a gaming product but not its name... What is it?" So I *hope* it's on-topic! Elsewise we really should revisit the tag. 94 open questions, one closed (for not having *any* detail), so it seems fine.

Comment: @nitsua60 Two of which are mine, both of which were found very quickly despite my having googled everything I could recall about them.

Comment: Adding a bounty to this question might help find the person who knows the answer.

Comment: I found a 2008 listing at https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/2008-11-13-tabletop-rpg-podcasts.424315/ for "HeadGames Podcast episodes: Horror RPGs." but the links are all dead.

Comment: How did you access the podcast? Was it on the radio, on the net - where you using a software like itunes or audible? If it was on the radio, what is the city where the park is?

Comment: It was a traditional RSS feed based podcast, as in, the technical definition of podcast. I don't have the computer I would have been using for podcatching at the time anymore, or I could try to get the subscriptions out of my podcatcher.